# joining select statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to do a inner join in my query but I don´t know how to summarize my two select statements into one query.

This is the first query:

```
 select 
          Machine  
        , EventDefinition
        , Duration
        , sum(Duration) over (partition by 1) As Total
        , Duration/sum(Duration) over (partition by 1)*100 AS Distribution
        ,case when EventCategory < 0.05 Then 'NOT INCL' ELSE 'OK' END AS Under3Min

     from (

           Select 
    SystemName AS Machine
    , EventDefinition
    , EventDate
    , EventStartDateTime
    , IsNull(EventEndDateTime, GETDATE()) as EventEndDateTime
    , Sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float))*24 as Duration
    ,Sum(case when CustomEvent = 'without Stop' then cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)*24 else 0 end) as EventCategory
        FROM tDataCategory                  
        WHERE EventDate >= @StartDateTime
        AND EventDate <= @EndDateTime
        AND SystemName = '201'
Group BY SystemName, eventdefinition, eventstartdatetime,  eventenddatetime, EventDefinition, EventDate, CustomEvent
    ) as t
    WHERE CustomEvent <> 'without Stop' 
        OR (CustomEvent = 'without Stop' AND t.EventCategory >=0.05)

    group by EventDefinition
            , Duration
        ,Machine
        ,EventCategory
```

output:
[image]
and my second query:

```
   SELECT DataValue = case when Prod = 0 then 0 else ISNULL(100.0 / Prod * Scrap, 0) end, 
    Value = GoodUnits/TheoreticalUnits *100, 
        FROM (
        Select intervaldate as DateValue, intervalDateWeek as Datum, tsystem.Name as Name, ProductName as Product, teamname as Team,
    SUM(case when IssueName in ('A1', 'A2') then calculationUnitsInitial else 0 end) as Scrap,
    Sum(case when IssueName = 'Prod' then calculationUnitsInitial else 0 end) as Prod,
    SUM(GoodUnits) 

As GoodUnits,
SUM(TheoreticalUnits) As TheoreticalUnits,

from tCount inner join tsystem ON tCount.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDate >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 1, getdate()), 0)  
and IntervalDate <= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
AND ((DATEPART(dw, IntervalDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0,1)
    and tsystem.Name = '201'

    group by intervaldate, tsystem.Name, intervaldateweek, ProductName, teamname
    ) as s
```

output:
[image]

I tried it to add in my query two select statements. But if I do this the output is wrong. I really don´t know how I should join this two queries.

I would like to do then this calculation: `Distribution * (1 - Value)`

`Distribution` from the first query and `Value` from the second query

Comment: We know even less what you want... Describe output from current queries, and the expected combined result.

Comment: @jarlh: I edited my question

Comment: Did your second query returns only one row

Comment: no, it returns 8 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the first and second result set has to be joined based on A.Machine=B.Name

Try like this,

```
SELECT A.Distribution * (1 - B.Value)
FROM (
    SELECT Machine
        ,EventDefinition
        ,Duration
        ,sum(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS Total
        ,Duration / sum(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) * 100 AS Distribution
        ,CASE 
            WHEN EventCategory < 0.05
                THEN 'NOT INCL'
            ELSE 'OK'
            END AS Under3Min
    FROM (
        SELECT SystemName AS Machine
            ,EventDefinition
            ,EventDate
            ,EventStartDateTime
            ,IsNull(EventEndDateTime, GETDATE()) AS EventEndDateTime
            ,Sum(cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime AS FLOAT)) * 24 AS Duration
            ,Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN CustomEvent = 'without Stop'
                        THEN cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime AS FLOAT) * 24
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS EventCategory
        FROM tDataCategory
        WHERE EventDate >= @StartDateTime
            AND EventDate <= @EndDateTime
            AND SystemName = '201'
        GROUP BY SystemName
            ,eventdefinition
            ,eventstartdatetime
            ,eventenddatetime
            ,EventDefinition
            ,EventDate
            ,CustomEvent
        ) AS t
    WHERE CustomEvent <> 'without Stop'
        OR (
            CustomEvent = 'without Stop'
            AND t.EventCategory >= 0.05
            )
    GROUP BY EventDefinition
        ,Duration
        ,Machine
        ,EventCategory
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DataValue = CASE 
            WHEN Prod = 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE ISNULL(100.0 / Prod * Scrap, 0)
            END
        ,Value = GoodUnits / TheoreticalUnits * 100
        ,NAME
    FROM (
        SELECT intervaldate AS DateValue
            ,intervalDateWeek AS Datum
            ,tsystem.NAME AS NAME
            ,ProductName AS Product
            ,teamname AS Team
            ,SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN IssueName IN (
                            'A1'
                            ,'A2'
                            )
                        THEN calculationUnitsInitial
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS Scrap
            ,Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN IssueName = 'Prod'
                        THEN calculationUnitsInitial
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS Prod
            ,SUM(GoodUnits) AS GoodUnits
            ,SUM(TheoreticalUnits) AS TheoreticalUnits
            ,
        FROM tCount
        INNER JOIN tsystem ON tCount.systemid = tsystem.id
        WHERE IntervalDate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 1, getdate()), 0)
            AND IntervalDate <= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
            AND ((DATEPART(dw, IntervalDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (
                0
                ,1
                )
            AND tsystem.NAME = '201'
        GROUP BY intervaldate
            ,tsystem.NAME
            ,intervaldateweek
            ,ProductName
            ,teamname
        ) AS s
    ) B ON A.Machine = B.NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did the same but in the output there is no result. The result is empty

Comment: I did used a `LEFT JOIN` now it shows me the results of the first select Statement but not from the second select statement. What can I do to get the output from the second statement?

Comment: Please check the A.Machine = B.NAME values of first & second select and ensure atleast a particular value is exist in both selects

Comment: Yes your right I forgot to check the second statement. Now both statements have the same values. Thanks a lot. This works now very well

Comment: I have got one question: How can i do a sum of the events. In the output one Event displays 3 or 5 times and I would like to see the sum of this event. How can I do a sum?